# Websites or books about the Torah and history of the world

Tags: history, product-recommendation, jewish-books, science, archaeology

I am looking for recommendations of good websites and books that talk about various ways of understanding the 'conflicts' between the Torah and a modern understanding of the age of the universe, the history of mankind, and events like the Flood.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 7):

[The Challenge of Creation](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Challenge_of_Creation.html?id=wcbInOxGeNUC) by [R. Natan Slifkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natan_Slifkin)

[Torah, Chazal, and Science](https://books.google.com/books?id=_kEYnwEACAAJ&dq=torah%20chazal%20and%20science&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR4bna7pfkAhUChOAKHQYDAeUQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ) by [R. Moshe Meiselman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Meiselman)

These two books contain very different approaches; in fact, the latter may be considered largely a rebuttal to the former. Between the two of them, you should be able to cover the main approaches.

Answer (score 5):

*Immortality, Resurrection and the Age of the Universe: A Kabbalistic View* by Rabbi Kaplan discusss many of these topics.

See the table of contents:

> 1. The age of the universe
> 2. Longevity and immortality in Judaic sources
> 3. On the resurrection
> 4. Astrology: stars and angles
> 5. Male and female

Answer (score 4):

Here are 3 books not already mentioned which are highly relevant and which I appreciated

- **Gerald Schroeder: [The Science of God: The Convergence of Scientific and Biblical Wisdom](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439129584) (2009)** which "demonstrates the surprising parallels between a variety of Biblical teachings and the findings of biochemists, paleontologists, astrophysicists, and quantum physicists. In a brilliant and wide-ranging discussion of key topics that have divided science and religion—free will, the development of the universe, the origin of life, and the origin of man—Schroeder argues that the latest science and a close reading of the Bible are not just compatible but interdependent."
- **Gerald Schroeder: [The Hidden Face of God: Science Reveals the Ultimate Truth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743203259) (2002)** which "explains why cutting-edge scientific theories point to a great plan underlying the universe"
- **R Aryeh Carmell & Cyril Domb: [Challenge: Torah Views on Science and Its Problems](https://smile.amazon.com/Challenge-Torah-Views-Science-Problems/dp/0873061748) (1988)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a comprehensive compendium of the Rebbe’s discussions on science topics as related to the Torah: [Mind over Matter: The Lubavitcher Rebbe on Science, Technology, and Medicine](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=10514&L=1), compiled by Rabbi Joseph Ginsburg and Professor Herman Branover, edited and translated by Arnie Gotfryd, Ph.D. (Jerusalem: Shamir, 2003).

Answer (score -1):

A great book:

The [Challenge of Creation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9652295949): Judaism's Encounter with Science, Cosmology, and Evolution by Rabbi Natan Slifkin

A great [essay](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v16/mj_v16i36.html#CIO) regarding the flood by Rabbi Marc Shapiro

A good site:

[Rationalist Judaism](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/?m=1)

Comment: I strongly caution [Meiselman's Torah, Chazal and Science](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2013/10/torah-chazal-and-science.html?m=1). It is anti-scientific and dishonesty portrays the Torah and science dispute.

Answer (score -3):

I am a Reform Jew, so I think you should read at least one book from reform rabbi.

I think "The God Upgrade, Finding your 21st Century Spirituality in Judaism’s 5000 Year Old Tradition" By Rabbi Jamie S. Korngold, Jewish Lights Publishing, 2011, 143 pages, is a great source.

Comment: Her site is the Adventure Rabbi.

Comment: I was unaware that Reform Judaism specifically ignores non Reform Rabbis

Comment: We usually keep to ourselves. But I think all rabbis are sound.

Comment: By the way I don't think anyone says Judaism is a 5000 year old tradition...not sure what that says about the author's credentials

Comment: I thought so. The Torah is very old.

Comment: No, the Torah is at least 3,000 years old. And definitely not 5,000! Not sure where she gets that... ?...

Answer (score -4):

They are many good sites to learn about Judaism, but the best, in my opinion, is Israel Drazin. He reviews books and prefers rational Judaism. Here is his website:https://booksnthoughts.com/

He writes a total of 50 books. My favorite is “Maimonides: Reason above all” by Rabbi Israel Drazin.

Mesora is good, too. http://www.mesora.org/

But if you want to study the conflict between science and Torah, the age of the universe or Genesis, and Noah’s flood, and how to reconcile these things, I recommend you read “Genesis and the Big Bang” by physicist Gerald Schroeder and read about Noah from philosopher and rabbi, Dr. Israel Drazin. They will answer your questions.

Comment: Which book by Rabbi Drazin addresses the OPs question? As of now your references to him are tangential.

Comment: The book I mentioned in the answer, "Maimonides: Reason above all," though strictly about Maimonides, will answer most of his questions, which is why it remains relevant. I did add new books to my answer, which do answer these as well.

Comment: You added one book. What is it in the book about Maimonides that will answer his questions about conflicts between modern understanding of history and what the Torah says? I'm just trying to improve your answer, which as of now is vague save for the Gerald Schroeder book

Comment: I added two books. Drazin and Schroeder, Both answer this well. Schroeder is more based on the sciences, such as creation, age of the universe, and science while Drazin is more leaning towards philosophy. The Maimonides book mentions Noah and theoretically, answers the question regarding Noah and the flood. Besides, it is imperative to know Maimonides.

Comment: Drazin rejects all the principles of normative Judaism. From a quick perusal of his essays it seems he does not believe in Sinaitic Revalation (though I did not see a clear statement on this), he rejects the Oral Law, and he even has an essay titled " The Torah doesn’t expect people to obey its laws." He also denies the immortality of the soul and reward or punishment after death.

Comment: @simyou I'll do you one better: a Drazin article where he espouses the old 'Bible Criticism' claim that Moshe didn't actually write the Torah: https://www.uncensoredjudaism.com/en/archives/1775

Comment: Actually Rabbi Micah Goodman agrees with Rabbi Drazin, writing that the, “Torah is a great human achievement but only a human achievement.” Since G-d is inactive in human affairs, it follows that G-d did not write the Torah. Drazin also thinks that the Oral Torah was not revealed at Sinai but is written by divine inspiration. He rejects heaven and hell and reward and punishment as childish. These views are not normative Judaism, but they are more realistic. I agree with Rabbi Drazin. I am a rationalist and I also think this is Maimonides' view.

Comment: Jews are not judged by their beliefs but their behavior, their actions. Rabbi Marc Shapiro shows in his works that Jews can believe in anything so long as they keep the mitzvot as the rabbis explain them.

Comment: PS Moshe probably did not write the entire Torah. This is acceptable because the Torah is, as Rabbi Goodman says, a "human achievement." Moshe probably wrote most of it.